# expressing point position within a circle as a percentage of arbitrary segments

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry

Ok, so... here's what I'm trying to do. In HTML/JS. With a math knowledge that would embarrass a twelve-year old.

With, say, 20 checkboxes on a page, the user picks.. five of them. A circle then appears on the page (I'd anticipate using one of the canvas libraries like Raphael) with their five answers arranged around it. So that's the first thing I don't know how to do; split a circle into x equal segments. Strange, foreign terms like "cos" and "sin" are looming on the horizon.

But then it gets even more fun: the user can click a point on the circle. And that point is translated into some sort of percentage value for each of the segments. So if the user checks Happy, Grumpy, Sneezy, Dopey and Bashful, and clicks the circle, I can tell them that they're 37% Happy, 42% Dopey and 21% Sneezy.

The best analogy is probably a colour-picker wheel, but I can't find any JS ones that I could repurpose. A pie chart is close - and there's a nice Raphael demo - but I've got a feeling that the fixed boundaries of a pie chart segment is going to take me down the wrong route for estimating percentage positions within the circle as a whole.

So, given my vague and poorly thought out request, and the noticeable absence of any "here's what I've tried so far" code - because I don't have the foggiest where to even start, apart from high school trigonometry books, can anyone suggest any code libraries or snippets that might get me at least pointing in the right direction?

Thanks :)

========================

Edit : 
Wow, thanks for all the answers. I'll try to refine the question/s a bit:

I'm going to need to draw a circle with x number of points arranged equally around its circumference. The number of points will correlate to the number of checkboxes that the user checked.

That's the first bit I'm stuck on: I reckon that I can draw a circle, with dimensions and at a position on the page of my own choosing, (using Raphael or similar canvas library) but how can I calculate what the x/y pixel coordinates of those points should be on the circle circumference?

The second bit: the user then clicks anywhere in the circle. I guess what I'd do is calculate how far each of the circumference points are from that user click point - I'm not sure how to do that, apart from a vague suspicion it involves imaginary triangles - and then how much of a total distance each of those distances are. That last bit, at least, I can manage.

Actually, this is starting to make sense. I'm still not sure how the trig stuff works but it's amazing what typing your problem out so that strangers will understand it can do to help your own understanding...

Comment: I think you need to refine your question a bit. You say that you are not sure how to split a circle "into x equal segments," but if the segments are equal, then calculating the percentage is pretty easy, as each wedge is the same size. Or is that a different circle?

Comment: I believe the relevant math is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Concerning your third paragraph, can you elaborate on how you determine the percentage values? Suppose I click right in the middle of the Grumpy segment, what are my scores? If I click closer to the edge or center of the circle, how do the percentages change?

Comment: If I'm understanding it right, what you describe in your third paragraph can't be done in a meaningful way. The user has only two "degrees of freedom" (e.g., X-coordinate and Y-coordinate; or, distance-from-center and direction-from-center), but these percentages require four (e.g. Happiness, Grump, Dopeydom, and Sneezitude, with Bash being 100% minus the sum of those).

Comment: +1  "amazing what typing your problem out so that strangers will understand can do" - known as rubber ducking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to revise your question to explain more clearly what you are trying to do.  In the meantime, I can give you the following information that may help you get started.

First of all, you'll need to know the locations of the five checkboxes that the user selects.  In order to do this, the jQuery library offers some convenient functions such as `$.position` and `$.offset`.

Your question does not make clear exactly how the circle you want to draw is positioned in relation to the five checkboxes that the user clicks.  As for actually drawing the circle, you may want to use something like the HTML5 canvas element.  I've not yet used it myself, so I can't tell you much about it.

You might want to try asking another question on StackOverflow about how to draw a circle on your web page once you've computed the center and radius of the circle.

As for doing the math about the circle, you need to know that a circle can be parameterized on an x-y plane by the following equations:

```
x = x0 + r cos(theta)
y = y0 + r sin(theta)
```

where (x0,y0) is the center of the circle, r is the radius of the circle, and theta ranges over 0 to 2*Pi radians (0 to 360 degrees)

Let us know more about what you're doing and we can give you some more specific information.

Comment: Re: "you'll need to know the locations of the five checkboxes that the user selects": I don't think so. By my reading, the checkboxes are just normal checkboxes, used like normal checkboxes. The user uses them to choose what categories go on the circle.